# in typescript, how to access an or object?

Tags: typescript

here is my typescript code

```
interface NameHolder {
  name: string
}

type Compound = string | NameHolder

function calc_it(): Compound { //there are many function of this type
  return { name: 'daniel' }
}

const ans = calc_it()
console.log(ans.name)
```

I get an error on the last line which read

> "Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Compound'.

I understand why is it: `ans` is a can be either a string or a an object with one attribute `name` so the compiler cannot validate `ans.name`

my queestion is: is there any way to make that error go away by either:

- changing the console.log(ans.name) to include a cast of some sort
- some kind of global defintion to relax that error checking

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html

Comment: In general, you should provide the "minimum" constraint for the result of a function. Since you always return a `NameHolder`-like object, there's no reason to declare a possible `string`. Simply declare to return a `NameHolder`.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this, you can perform a type check to narrow down the type:

```js
const ans = calc_it();
if (typeof ans === 'string') {
  // Handle the string case
  console.log(ans);
} else {
  // Handle the object case
  console.log(ans.name);
}
```

Alternatively, if you're sure that the returned value will always have a `name` property, you can assert the type:

```js
const ans = calc_it() as NameHolder;
console.log(ans.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yow want to narrow it:

```
interface NameHolder {
  name: string
}

type Compound = string | NameHolder

function calc_it(): Compound { //there are many function of this type
  return { name: 'daniel' }
}

const ans = calc_it()
// oh, ans is either `string` or `NameHolder`.
// `string` does not have property named `name`, so TS complains...

if ("name" in ans) {
  // Yay! it narrows down to `NameHolder`!
  console.log(ans.name)
}
```

There are few ways to narrowing is happen, such as `property in obj`, `typeof obj === "whatever"`, `x is T`, `x asserts T`, ...

Answer (score 0):

You might try a check using the ternary operator like this : `console.log(typeof ans == 'object' ? ans.name : ans)`